# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to pull a binary from our repo in Artifactory that is of HTTPS.

```
/var/chef/cookbooks/app/providers/setup.rb:48:in `determineRepoURL'
/var/chef/cookbooks/app/providers/setup.rb:86:in `deploy_compile_time_config_application'
/var/chef/cookbooks/app/providers/setup.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in class_from_file'
/var/chef/cookbooks/app/providers/setup.rb:20:in `block in class_from_file'
...

[2019-03-26T17:11:39-07:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2019-03-26T17:11:39-07:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2019-03-26T17:11:39-07:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 5 resources updated
[2019-03-26T17:11:39-07:00] ERROR: app_setup[test] (app::default line 40) had an error: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Previously I had

```
def determineRepoURL(*param)
        url = "#{repository_url}/api/search/pattern?pattern=#{param[0]}:#{name}/#{version}/*#{param[1]}"
        uri = URI(url)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
        request.basic_auth "#{user}", "#{token}"
        response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
        result = JSON.parse(response.body)
        list = result['files'].sort.reverse
        return list[0]
end
```

after adding

```
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

I still have the same error. However, for some reason, this only happens on Chef's 11.8.2, I tried my script with Chef's 12.6.0 and I did not encounter this SSL certificate issue, does anyone have a bypass for 11.8.2 as I do not have access to 12.6.0

Ruby version: 1.8.7

OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa sorry, my question is how to fix this issue without using Chef 12.6.0?